# Logical page error while attempting to insert data

Tags: sql-server-2005, corruption

I am getting the following error while trying to insert a row in a table:

> Attempt to fetch logical page (1:12032) in database 19 failed. It
>   belongs to allocation unit 72057594069450752 not to 72057594051166208.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a database corruption so try the command

```
DBCC CHECKDB
```

And The command

```
 dbcc checktable ( 'dbo.TableName', REPAIR_REBUILD )
```

Before that Refer to BOL to see about the commands .

Comment: Thanks Tareq.. the command worked..Now the error is gone..